# Mac OS X accessing Windows Share

Tags: macos, network, windows, file-sharing, smb

Strange thing keeps happening with one of my clients. They are running 3 iMacs 2of which are running 10.9.3 and 1 is running 10.9.4. While they are accessing a Windows share, they can be working away quite happily until it comes to saving where they no longer have access to the file opened from the server and have to save as a new file. They are accessing using smb://{servername}/{share}

What would cause this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Apple [moved to SMB2 in Mavericks](http://appleinsider.com/articles/13/06/11/apple-shifts-from-afp-file-sharing-to-smb2-in-os-x-109-mavericks).  There have been many reported issues regarding Macs using SMB2 to access Windows shares.  There's even [a site](http://macsmbissues.com/) dedicated to this specific set of issues!

For a dated, but good explanation of work-arounds see [this ZDNet article](http://appleinsider.com/articles/13/06/11/apple-shifts-from-afp-file-sharing-to-smb2-in-os-x-109-mavericks).

TL;DR

Have your users try `cifs://` instead of `smb://` (assuming your Windows share supports CIFS)...and hope that 10.9.4 comes with an SMB2 fix. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @thankyour. I haven't tried cifs:// yet. The strange thing is that I have another client which is using a Mac Server running 10.8.4 with clients running Leopard, Snow Leopard, Lion, Mountain Lion and Mavericks, all using afp:// and have similar issues. I know there are issues when it comes to Adobe as they say it is not designed to work from a network share, but it also has the same issues with Word, Excel, Pages and others aswell